# Synchronize rendering between native OpenGL and WebGL in WKWebview (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, webgl, wkwebview

For an iOS app we are developing, I am trying to tightly synchronize the rendering of a 3D scene happening in a `WKWebView` (using `three.js/WebGL`) and the `OpenGL` rendering happening on a separate `UIView` in the native side of the app (Objective-C). Each time the rendering loop of the native side prepares and presents a frame, a call to a JS function is done via the `WKWebView` `evaluateJavaScript` method to render one frame using `three.js`. The result is that, even though both rendering calls are frame synchronous, visually there's a tiny lag between the display of both scenes that doesn't work for our purposes. This is likely due to the fact that both renderings are happening in separate threads (`OpenGL` contexts?).

My question is: is it possible to completely `synchronize` the display of both a `WKWebView/WebGL` and a `UIView` (`UIGLViewProtocol`)?